# Error encountered while reading from module 'RealmSwift'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, realm

Summary: Swift allows me to import `RealmSwift`, but it doesn't allow me to create a new instance of the `Realm` class (or type any code using Realm keywords). I don't have any other code because this is a brand new project.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Make a new Xcode project
2. In Terminal, cd to the project and type 'pod init'
3. Open the Podfile and add the pod 'RealmSwift'
4. Open the Xcode project's workspace and go to the AppDelegate file
5. Import 'RealmSwift'
6. Make a new variable and make it an instance of the Realm class

Expected Results: The program runs and lets me make a new instance of the Realm class.

Actual Results: The program crashes with the following errors:

> Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6" & "error: fatal error
>   encountered while reading from module 'RealmSwift'.

Also, at the top of the file where I wrote the code using Realm keywords, it says:

> An Internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore...

This is a Swift Compiler Error btw

Version/Build:

**Realm version:** 3.7.4

**Xcode version:** 4.1

**Swift version:** 4.1

**configuration:** MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra

Comment: Did you run 'pod update' after adding it to the podfile?

Comment: yes. everything was at the most updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a *Dynamic Framework* instead? I did use CocoaPods in the past but using a dynamic framework simplifies the process. Download the frameworks from here:
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#installation

And follow the instructions:
[image: realm_dynamic-framework_installation]

After you've dragged the framework into your project, it looks like so:
[image: realm_dynamic-framework_in_project]

Now, the hurdle is that since this is not done through pod files, you cannot automatically update the Realm version. This you will have to do manually by downloading the newest version of the framework from time to time.

Comment: It still didn't work. Getting the same error. But thank you for trying!

Comment: Please post the full code of your AppDelegate, so I can take a look at what’s going on with your Realm.

Comment: It was just the default code. The only things I added were "import RealmSwift" at the top and

Comment: do { let realm = try Realm() } catch { print(error) }        -----------                                                       The "Realm()" is supposed to change color, but mine didn't

Comment: I put the do-try-catch block in the function -- func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)

Comment: I know you're just using the default code, but it makes it very difficult to find the cause of the error without seeing your code in context.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xcode packages, you can replace "Up to next major" by the exact version of the package (10.19.0 in my case)